# <table> size management with Angular, Html and Less

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, less

I have a table made up of a large number of data items, which means that I can no longer see/enter the new values, as shown in this image :

[image: first-problem]

So I tried adding a low scroll, I thought it would save space and visibility for my th and td, but it didn't, here's the code

1. HTML :

   ```
       <div class="conditions-table-container grid__container">
         <table class="conditions-table-other">
           <tbody>
               <tr class="conditions-table__header grid__header">
                   <td
                       class="grid__big-column grid__inner-padding"
                       translation="condition"
                   >
                       Condition
                   </td>
                   <td
                       class="grid__big-column grid__inner-padding"
                       translation="unit"
                   >
                       Unit
                   </td>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
   ```
2. Less :

   ```
   .conditions-table-container {
   margin-bottom: 16px;

   .conditions-table {
       width: 100%;
       &__header {
           text-align: center;
       }

       &__input {
           width: 45px;
       }
   }
   .conditions-table-other {
       display: block;
       overflow-x: auto;
       white-space: nowrap;
       width: auto;
       &__header {
           text-align: center;
       }

       &__input {
           width: 100px;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Result :

[image: second-problem]

---

I really hope to have some help on this subject, thank you in advance.